# Redux state update causing React component to render unnecessarily

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutability, immutable.js

I’m experiencing a few performance issues in my react / redux app.

I’m working with an object in one of my reducers which is quite deep. It contains an object named `list` which holds a collection of objects.

```
const state = {
  list: {
    one: {
      id: 'one',
      name: 'One',
      active: false
    },
    two: {
      id: 'two',
      name: 'Two',
      active: false
    }
  }
}
```

Each item in the object is used to render a component. This component will access the properties of the item like so:

```
const List = (props) => {
  const listItems = Object.keys(props.list).map((key) => {
    const item = props.list[key];
    return (
      <Item key={item.id} active={item.active}>
        {item.name}
      </Item>
    );
  });

  return <ul>{listItems}</ul>;
};
```

However, every time I run through the following code, my component (which is a PureComponent) renders.

```
case UPDATE_LIST_ITEM:
  return {
    ...state,
    list: {
      ...state.list,
      [payload.itemId]: {
        ...state.list[payload.itemId],
      },
    },
  };
```

The Redux docs mention that "every level of nesting must be copied and updated appropriately", yet, I'm not even updating any values, but just copying the object.

I'm not sure what could be done here. Is this a good time to implement a library like Immutable.js?

**Update:**

Also (I'm not too sure if this helps but), the following redux update does not cause my component to render:

```
case UPDATE_LIST_ITEM:
  return {
    ...state,
    list: {
      ...state.list,
      [payload.itemId]: state.list[payload.itemId],
    },
  };
```

Comment: Seems like every time your reducer returns a new state, it's going to trigger a re-render on every component that consumes that entire object. Maybe I'm not understanding you. Is your object vastly more complex than that one/two guy above?

Comment: It has a few more properties, but that's about it

Comment: I believe the issue is being caused by the object pointer changing and therfore causing a render. I'm wondering whether I should be performing a check to make sure I should return a new/updated copy of the state and whether something like Immutable.js can help with that

Comment: What do your `mapState` functions look like?  You're probably handing the `PureComponent` a section of the state that is being updated, so yes, it will re-render.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean. I have a section where I map over `Object.keys(props.list)` to render the list items (shown in my question)

Comment: Show me `Object.keys(props.list)` where the props.list is coming from please

Comment: Thank you! I have updated my question to show the full List component

Comment: Where are you using <List/> ? Where are the props coming from

Comment: Please show the `mapStateToProps` function that pulls that value out of your Redux store.

Comment: I have a container component that passes the list props down to the `List` component like this: `<List list={this.props.reducerExample.list} />`

Comment: `const mapStateToProps = ({ reducerExample }) => ({reducerExample});`

Comment: I am getting confused myself now...  does my answer  make any sense to you? if you can put this on codepen I can debug better what is going on

Comment: Thanks. I'll get a demo set up, but I might not be able to do it until tomorrow

Comment: This all seems pretty tautological, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. Maybe you get better answers by posting an instance of the Action here. As a general remark: you have to create new object for the one you want to change and all its parents - you should almost always keep the ones that are unchanged

Comment: Okay, great! That's sort of what I was thinking was the case. Right now the action is firing based off of a web socket, so I guess the best solution would be to check if the state update is necessary or not rather than just firing it every time

Answer (score 0):

Your pure component is using `props.list` from the state. In your first reducer, by the time your code reaches that point you are updating the application state and if your component is getting `list` from the application state, the expected behaviour to re-render your component if the props value has changed.

If you do not want your component to re-render on every state change, you can control that with have to upgrade your component to class and control when and when not it should render. `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)`

[React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)

Comment: My list item is a class though (as it's a PureComponent). My understanding was that PureComponents implements its own shallow prop and state comparison, so there would not be a reason to use `shouldComponentUpdate`

Comment: The react docs also mention: "Consider using the built-in PureComponent instead of writing shouldComponentUpdate() by hand. PureComponent performs a shallow comparison of props and state, and reduces the chance that you’ll skip a necessary update."

Comment: Your main concern was that component is re-rendering unnecessarily right?  What I see happening basically is this:  `case UPDATE_LIST_ITEM:` is invoked and state changes.  mapStateToProps updating ` <List />` which is causing your pure component to re render. Maybe you are dispatching unnecessarily which is causing the unwanted rerenders?